# Difficulty in avoiding many 'if statements'

Tags: java, performance

I am aiming to optimise the speed of my code, as it will be run many times a second. I need to check individually as to which arrow keys are being held down and execute code accordingly. 
If the arrow keys should result in diagonal movement, I'd like this movement to be slower in each axis individually, so I can not just consider each key individually as far as I can tell.

Also, if three keys are being held, I'd like to be able to ignore the two that would cancel each other out.

Is there any easy way of doing this?

For example, my code currently looks along the following lines:

```
if ( input.isKeyDown ( Input.KEY_UP ) && input.isKeyDown ( Input.KEY_RIGHT ) ) {
    // code
} 
if ( input.isKeyDown ( Input.KEY_DOWN ) && input.isKeyDown ( Input.KEY_RIGHT ) ) {
    // code
} 
...

if ( input.isKeyDown ( Input.KEY_LEFT ) ) {
    // code
}
etc.
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit: Both this and my previous question I posted a while ago have received a negative vote. Can anyone explain why I am receiving these; is there something I'm missing?

Comment: use else statements here and there. what do you mean, cancel each other out?

Comment: Have you actually identified a performance bottleneck at these conditionals? Or did you just decide that they need optimized? Premature optimization is the root of all software evil.

Comment: @Stultuske *"what do you mean, cancel each other out?"* Like pressing left and right (or up and down) together (I'm not OP, but this sounds to be what he's referring to).

Comment: @Stultuske For example, if I hold the left, up, and right arrows, I would like the total movement horizontally to be zero (the left and right directions cancel each other) and the upwards movement to be a "full amount" (as opposed to being reduced due to horizontals or being increased due to addition of both directions).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I have not actually, I just assumed I would ideally want to make sure there was not a more efficient method considering this code will be running many times and at least 8 if statements is generally not the most efficient way to go about things. I do not have much experience with these situations however, you may indeed be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still check individual keys to get a general direction then normalize it and apply speed to get the final movement target.

Example:

You start with direction 0/0. Now you check the up key and if it is pressed add 1 to the y-component resulting in direction 0/1. Then you check the right key and if it is pressed add 1 to x, thus resulting in 1/1.

Repeat the same for down and left (though you'd subtract 1) and if they are set too you'll get direction 0/0 again.

Now assume we have direction 1/1: normalizing that to length 1 would result in direction 0.7/0.7. Multiply that with some speed, let's say 5, and your target location would be 3.5/3.5.

Of course, if the direction has length 0 already you shouldn't do anything.

A final note though: This probably won't speed up your code but I'd doubt you'll have performance issues here. It should be rather fast as it is (unless you're doing fancy stuff you didn't share) and assuming this is for a game you'll have other areas where more performance could be gained (algorithms, data layout, rendering etc.).

Comment: I like this method, and am frustrated I did not think of it myself; it's much like actually calculating the totality of different velocity vectors, which is fundamentally what this problem is about. Thank you.